# Can you make a conditional inside a <div> element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've trying to find an answer for this. But I want to make a conditional in this return statement:

```
document.getElementById('bookList').innerHTML = data.map(item => {
  return `<div>
    <div>Title: ${item.title}</div>
    <div>Author: ${item.author}</div>
    <div>Pages: ${item.pages}</div>
    if (fields.checkbox.checked) {
      console.log("hello")
    } else {
      console.log("not logged")
    }
    <button>Remove</button>
  </div>`

})
```

Without much luck because it returns the string as it is not with the if/else statement. Is there anyway you can make it an if/else statement even if it is a div?

Comment: What do you expect the return value to evaluate to then? Would you want "hello" to come between the "Pages:" `div` and the `button`? Without it being wrapped in its own `div`? Can you provide the literal result you expect for either case? BTW: `.map` returns an array... not really the right data type for `innerHTML` assignment... that will result in commas.

Comment: I would recommend to make the if check before you call the return so you keep it simple.

Comment: @trincot how can you avoid it being an array. What's an alternative for the map method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ternary` operator inside the template literals ${}

```
document.getElementById('bookList').innerHTML = data.map(item => {
  return `<div>
    <div>Title: ${item.title}</div>
    <div>Author: ${item.author}</div>
    <div>Pages: ${item.pages}</div>
    ${fields.checkbox.checked ? console.log("hello") : console.log("not logged")}
    <button>Remove</button>
  </div>`

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and you can do it several ways. Or you can create all your elements like this:

Option 1:

```js
const container = document.createElement('div');
const text = document.createElement('p');
text.textContent = "Lorum";
container.appendChild(text);
document.appendChild(container);
```

Option 2 like you started:

```js
return `
<div>
  <p>
    ${1 == 1 ? "someText" : ''}
  </p>
</div>
`
```